# Android | Not able to track "ecommerce purchase" event in GA using GTM + firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I followed the following docs for creating Tag and trigger in GTM for "purchase" event:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

I am able to track “events” and “screen views” in GA using GTM + Firebase but not the “ecommerce purchase”.
I can see logs in firebase debug view for “ecommerce purchase” event, but it is not getting recorded in Google Analytics.

**Trigger for ecommerce_purchase:**

[image]

**Tag configuration:**

[image]

**Firebase Debug View:**

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure to [enable](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6032539?hl=en) Enhnaced Ecommerce in Google Analytics?

Comment: @faridghar, Yes It is enabled.

Comment: GA may not record the hit if it is data is invalid. Is there anything (errors/warnings) in the app console output (having your firebase+gtm sdk in debug mode). Also, use https proxy (like fiddler/wireshark/charles) to catch actual request to GA endpoint and send it to /debug/ to check if data is malformed

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar situation. Try hardcoding the Tracking ID field & it worked for me.